# Add flag during run time (Xcode Instruments)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, instruments

I am using Instruments to debug my allocation in my iOS app and was wondering if there was a way to add flags to the trace while the code is running. For example, I'd like a flag that says "user tapped on button X" to be added automatically once the user tapped on that button.

From what it seems from Apple docs, you can only add those flags 'after the fact'.

Comment: There is DTSignalFlag but it doesn't work on the device, I've submitted a new feature request to bugreporter.apple.com I'd suggest you do as well

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach recommended here:

http://ioscodesnippet.com/post/43288248813/method-swizzling-in-objective-c

Basically, you can add a trace onto a particular method that you know you want to trace in advance by swizzling out the real implementation for your custom implementation which logs a tracing statement before calling the real implementation (in this case, you can override -[UIButton endTrackingWithTouch: withEvent:]).

Comment: Cached version of the site: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Q2ohZmB3DkkJ:https://ioscodesnippet.tumblr.com/post/43288248813/method-swizzling-in-objective-c+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=fi